# How to apply plugin to only one flavor in gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, newrelic, android-productflavors

I have a multi-flavored, multi-build-typed android project and I want to integrate the NewRelic plugin. But I have to apply it only for one of the customers, thus only for one product flavor.
NewRelic uses instrumentation and the plugin would generate code in other flavors if I applied the plugin there, and that is not permitted for us.

So my question is: How can I use the `apply plugin: something` command in the gradle file to be applied to only one of my flavors?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use this code:

```
if (!getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests()
        .toString().contains("Develop")){
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

`getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()` returns something like `[DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[:app:generateDevelopDebugSources],projectPath='null'}]` so as stated in the comments `Develop` must start with an uppercase.

Comment: This code work. But you need to pay attention that first letter of flavor name should be in Uppercase

Comment: Didn't worked when clicked assemble from the right side gradle menu...
When installed the app manually..

Comment: this almost works for me, but I noticed when type `./gradlew assembleDe` that the value in `getTaskRequests` is also `assembleDe` - when I expected it to be already expanded to `assembleDebug`

Comment: The code doesn't work. This prints an empty array "[]"
println("${getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()}")

Comment: I confirmed @Pavel comment.  Seems to work from within Android Studio but not when run from command line. This is all I get: [DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[build],projectPath='null'}]

Comment: Not working for me, when I do clean, rebuild, the value that I get is [defaulttaskexecutionrequest{args=[],projectpath='null'}]

Comment: @Fabio did you find a solution to the problem? E.g. running `./gradlew asF` instead of `./gradlew assembleFlavor` fails the solution proposed by this answer: the task request string contains `"asF"` but not `assembleFlavor`. That is a problem when trying to match e.g. `"Flavor"`!

Comment: Nope, I got tired of dealing with firebase and now distribute Apks with slack

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when running tests.

Comment: also if you give multiple sets in one command like: ```./gradlew assembleFlavor assembleFlavor2```, the same inclusion(exclusion is applied to both

Answer (score 17):

Tried different solutions, but none of them worked for me. This is what I came up with and seems to work as far as I tested:

`build.gradle`

```
productFlavors {
    someFlavorWithGoogleGcm {
        dimension "type"
        applicationId "com.example.withGcm"
        ext.useGoogleGcm = true
    }
    someFlavorWithoutGoogleGcm {
        dimension "type"
        applicationId "com.example.withoutGcm"
    }
}
```

And outside the configuration, inside the `build.gradle` file:

```
android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
    if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().toLowerCase().contains(flavor.name) && flavor.ext.useGoogleGcm) {
        println("Building flavor with Google GCM [${flavor.name}] - applying plugin")
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. However, I changed your if a little bit to `if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskNames().stream().filter { it.toLowerCase().contains(flavor.name) }.count() > 0 && flavor.ext.useGoogleGcm)`

Comment: It does not seem to be executing for me. I don't get the logs somehow and the plugin is just not applied. Added extra logs before the if statement, still no joy.

Comment: Seems that using .all instead of .each fixes it.

Comment: Failed for me with Gradle 7.0.2, the error was `Cannot get property 'shouldMinify' on extra properties extension as it does not exist`. So I needed to add the `ext.shouldMinify` property to all flavors (and set to according values)

Comment: this 'kinda' works, yes it does only apply the plugin when the ext is present, but for some reason `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` doesn't generate `R.string.default_web_client_id`

Comment: My guess is the `'com.google.gms.google-services'` plugin runs even before any actual build is running to generate `R.string.default_web_client_id`.

Answer (score 16):

I simply used `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` inside the flavor in app level build.gradle and it works just fine.

```
productFlavors {
    ..... your other flavors ....
    yourFlv {
        ....
        ....
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
}
```

No extra step needed.

Comment: I would suggest others use this

Comment: Wow, it really is that simple!

Comment: I used it for exact this use case. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the complements. If it really helped you, you may go ahead and hit vote up button. That will help others find it easily.

Comment: This works for builds through Android Studio, but didn't work for builds with Jenkins.

Comment: This is a syntax cheat, the plugin is still got involved when build other product flavor, tested with android gradle plugin version 4.2.0

Comment: good solution simple and easy to use #android
I recommend this solution for you all

Comment: This didn't work for me - plugin applied for all flavors when placed here.

Answer (score 10):

1. Define variable - `def fl`
2. Initialize variable in you Flavours (and/or builds)

   ```
       productFlavors {

               freeFlavour {
                   (...)
                   fl = "free"
               }

               paidFlavour {
                   (...)
                   fl = "paid"
               }
           }
   ```
3. Use if statement -

   `if (fl == "free") {
       apply plugin: something
   }`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. In my case (let's say I'm calling assembleFree), both blocks are executed so the value of fl is the name of the last declared flavour. Any other ideas?

Comment: This will be resolved in configuration time, and since this needs to go all over it, the fl will contain the last value.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution, but it is not the best so far.
So I'm not sure anymore, that what I wanted to do initially is possible.
The gradle file evaluation and the choosing of the right flavor and build type is in different phases of the gradle build, so what I've done is:

I use a build parameter from the command line. When that paramerer is true, I apply the plugin, when it is not even there, I also apply it (for IDE build).
I use Jenkins, so I could write that parameter in the build job.

build.gradle file:

```
// First we have to attach a task to the project, which will be running first
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(applyNewRelicByProperty)
}

// Then check on the parameter, which comes from the command line
task applyNewRelicByProperty {
    if(!project.hasProperty('compileNewRelic')) {
        // NewRelic on: 'compileNewRelic' property not set, so running from IDE.
        apply plugin: 'newrelic'
    } else if(project.hasProperty('compileNewRelic') && project.getProperties().get('compileNewRelic').equals('true')) {
        // NewRelic on: 'compileNewRelic' property is set and it is 'true'.
        apply plugin: 'newrelic'
    } else {
        // NewRelic off
        println("No NewRelic")
    }
}
```

And you have to run the gradle build by this:

```
assembleYourApp -PcompileNewRelic=true
```

Comment: This does not work for me as of today. Apparently, the `build.gradle` parser looks for `apply` statements before even evaluating project, hence nullifying the `if` checks.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Gradle 4.2, the approach by Tarps stopped working, so I ended up combining it with Erik's answer.

Set `ext.useGoogleGcm` for each flavour in your `build.gradle`:

```
productFlavors {
    a {
        ...
        ext.useGoogleGcm = true
    }
    b {
        ...
        ext.useGoogleGcm = false
    }
}
```

Then at the bottom of the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

afterEvaluate {
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.contains('GoogleServices') && it.name.contains(flavor.name.capitalize())
        }*.enabled = flavor.ext.useGoogleGcm
    }
}
```

In the output for your `assembleRelease` task, you should see tasks with "GoogleServices" in the name have run for those that are true and skipped for those that are false. If your build complains about `toCapitalize`, you could use `toLowerCase` on both `it.name` and `flavor.name`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the Google Services Gradle plugin, the following works.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching { it.name.contains("GoogleServices") && !it.name.contains(yourFlavorName) }*.enabled = false
}
```

where `yourFlavorName` is a capitalised string containing the name of your flavor that must apply the plugin; all other flavors don't use the plugin.

Note that the plugin is still applied to other flavors; this solution just disables the `*GoogleServices*` task(s) for them. That assumes that the Google Services Gradle plugin only applies changes by adding a task containing substring `"GoogleServices"`, which might not work in the future.

To check that this works, you can check the dependencies, e.g. like so:

`./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --configuration yourFlavorNameDebugCompileClasspath --dependency google | grep -i services`

That should show some dependencies for `yourFlavorName` but not for other flavor names:

`./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --configuration otherFlavorNameDebugCompileClasspath --dependency google | grep -i services`