# gradle: apply plugin only for specific flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-flavors, android-flavordimension

My Android gradle currently set a flavor dimension for using different push service. (One for baidu push and one for GCM) I would like to have my Android app only to import `google-services` for a GCM push build flavor. Is it possible to do it?

**P.S.** Because in order to use GCM in Android, I have to add the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line be at the bottom of my app/build.gradle file as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#introduction).

As a workaround in order to let the baidu flavor to be built successfully, I may need to place a dummy `google-services.json` for baidu.

**Update:**
I seem to find the answer in [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54) long github issue thread.

Comment: In your update, include a link to the post that solves the issue

Comment: can't you just apply the plugin for a specific build variant with `android.applicationVariants.all{ it.variantData.getVariantConfiguration().getFullName().capitalize(); //if here}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply plugin to only one flavor in gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379795/how-to-apply-plugin-to-only-one-flavor-in-gradle)

Comment: What is your solution? I am facing the same problem and the link https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54 doesn't seem to help.

I have multiple flavor and similar to your situation, some of them are for China and hence doesn't require Firebase. I am looking for ways to not run apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' for specific variants.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `build.gradle`(App)file add this code:

```
if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests()
        .toString().contains("YourGCMFlavorName")){
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

> **N.B.: First letter of flavor name must be in Uppercase**

**Update 2021-11-23:** Please note [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69387711/698373) by Prasoon Abhishek below.

Comment: I believe the negation is a mistake (?) - I mean if you're looking for the GCM flavor you then apply the GMS plugin, don't you?

Comment: Important. The first letter MUST be in upper case as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336869/5564683

Comment: Thank you Augusto Carmo. I have added this.

Comment: The solution by Prasoon does not work for me (with another plugin). The check on the Gradle task name does work as intended.

Answer (score 5):

I had this very same problem - I have a project that builds multiple apps, each app has two variants one distributed via Google Play and uses Google Play Services amd Firebase APIs, the other variant is distributed via Web download (mainly for AOSP devices) and cannot include either Google Play Services or Firebase APIs.

In our app/build.gradle file we didn't want any funky condition tests that didn't seem totally obvious, by that we meant "if variant == web then do not apply plug google play services". We also didn't want multiple copies of the file google-services.json, i.e. one per app, we wanted one that contained all the app bundles enabled for Google Play Services. This is because we add and remove apps quite regularly and want to manage those apps as one project in the Firebase console.

The solution was to create a distribution dimension, this dimension must be placed first in the flavorDimensions array (the com.google.gms.google-services plugin only looks in the first dimension for *google-services.json*).

```
    flavorDimensions 'distribution', 'application'
    productFlavors {
        store {
            dimension 'distribution'
        }
        web {
            dimension 'distribution'
            applicationIdSuffix ".nogms"
        }
        app1 {
            dimension 'application'
            applicationId 'com.example.app1'
        }
        app2 {
            dimension 'application'
            applicationId 'com.example.app2'
        }
```

The *distribution* dimension had two values - "store" and "web"

The *google-services.json* generated by the Firebase console was placed in the directory *app/src/store*.

In the *app/src/web* directory we placed a dummy google-services.json file with the following contents:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "0",
    "project_id": "api-project-0"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:0:android:0",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.app1.nogms"
        }
      },
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "none"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:0:android:0",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.app2.nogms"
        }
      },
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "none"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This keeps the plugin happy. (Non GMS app bundles need to be added to the "client":[] array as needed).

The GMS and Firebase libraries were conditionally included into the store flavors only:

```
dependencies {
    storeImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    storeImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2'
    storeImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
}
```

And finally the Google Play Services plugin was applied globally at the end of the build.gradle as instructed in https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank you!  Seems like you can't really keep the plugin from applying so using a dummy google-services.json seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply the dependency in specific build flavour definition in build.gradle

```
android{
      productFlavors {

         flavourName{
         apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This doesn't work.  With this solution the plugin is applied in other flavors as well