# greenDAO for only one flavor of the app

Tags: android, greendao, android-productflavors

I use greenDAO just in one flavor of the app, and I would like to avoid adding the dependency to the flavor that does not use it so that application is not bloated.

The problem that I'm having is that `apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'` is applied for both flavors which causes build script to fail for the flavor that does not use greenDAO.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'    

android {
   ...
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            ...    
        }
        pro {
            ...
        }
    }
}    

greendao {
   schemaVersion 1
}    

dependencies {
    proCompile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'
}
```

How could I solve this, any idea?

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, it looks like greenDAO builds all classes marked with @Entity even if they are in different flavor and puts them into folder `\build\generated\source\greendao\com\test\app\database` This causes build errors as classes can not be found (which of course could not be, as they are defined in different flavor).

Comment: "which causes build script to fail for the flavor that does not use greenDAO" -- what is the nature of the failure? I haven't used greenDAO personally, but usually a Gradle plugin will fail gracefully when it cannot find anything to process.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the remark, I tried to update the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Ick. That feels like a bug/limitation in the plugin itself. The best thing that I can think of is for you to isolate all your greenDAO stuff into a library module, then pull in that library module only for relevant flavor(s). If you need to keep this all in one module, in theory you could write a custom Gradle task that deletes the unnecessary files, then arrange to have that task be run automatically after whatever task the greenDAO plugin has that generates those files in the flavor(s) for which you are avoiding greenDAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently greenDao does not support this. The bug regarding this is open on their issue tracker on GitHub and let's hope it will be addressed soon.

Link to the issue: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/587

Answer (score 0):

**Don't put this code in any closure. Put them in the end of /app/build.gradle**

The core function:

```
def getCurrentFlavor(boolean firstUpper) {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String  tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    Pattern pattern

    if( tskReqStr.contains( "assemble" ) ) // to run ./gradlew assembleRelease to build APK
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else if( tskReqStr.contains( "bundle" ) ) // to run ./gradlew bundleRelease to build .aab
        pattern = Pattern.compile("bundle(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( tskReqStr )

    if( matcher.find() ) {
        String flavor = matcher.group(1)
        if (firstUpper) {
            return flavor
        } else {
            return flavor.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + flavor.substring(1)
        }
    } else {
        println "NO MATCH FOUND"
        return ""
    }
}
```

To make diffient greendaoSchemaVersion:

```
String currentFlavorDir = getCurrentFlavor(true)
if ("" != currentFlavorDir) {
    apply from: "/${currentFlavorDir}/app/constant.gradle"
    println "${currentFlavorDir} apply greenDaoSchemaVersion ${greendaoSchemaVersion}"
    greendao {
        schemaVersion greendaoSchemaVersion
    }
}
```

constant.gradle from flavor dir:

```
ext {
    greendaoSchemaVersion = youFlavorVersionNumber
}
```

To solve the problem what it generate two or more fields with same name in a file,  put this code:

core Processor:

```
class Processor {
    void processEntityAnnotation(boolean enable, File file) {
        StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder()
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("//@Entity")) {
                    if (enable) {
                        // replace with your own line
                        line = "@Entity(indexes = {@Index(value = \"createTime DESC\")})"
                        println ("processEntityAnnotation enable path: ${file.absolutePath}")
                    }
                } else if (line.startsWith("@Entity")) {
                    if (!enable) {
                        // replace with your own line
                        line = "//@Entity(indexes = {@Index(value = \"createTime DESC\")})"
                        println ("processEntityAnnotation disable path: ${file.absolutePath}")
                    }
                }
                newFile.append(line)
                newFile.append('\n')
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
            writer.write(newFile.toString())
        }

    }
}
```

task named "greendaoBefore" , to add comment:

```
tasks.register('greendaoBefore') {
    // Init this objects outside of "doLast"  in order to run with "org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true"
    String flavor = getCurrentFlavor(false)
    Processor processer = new Processor()
    File file0 = file("../flavor0/main/java/Entity.java")
    File file1 = file("../flavor1/main/java/Entity.java")
    File file2 = file("../flavor2/main/java/Entity.java")

    doLast {
        println "greendaoBefore"

        println "greendaoBefore ${flavor}"
        if (flavor == "flavor1") {
            println("processEntityAnnotation path1")
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(false, file0)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file1)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(false, file2)
        } else if (flavor == "flavor2") {
            println("processEntityAnnotation path2")
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(false, file0)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(false, file1)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file2)
        } else {
            println("processEntityAnnotation path0")
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file0)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(false, file1)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(false, file2)

        }
    }
}
```

task named "greendaoAfter", to cancel comment for git if needed:

```
tasks.register('greendaoAfter') {
    // Init this objects outside of "doLast"  in order to run with "org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true"
    String flavor = getCurrentFlavor(false)
    Processor processer = new Processor()
    File file0 = file("../flavor0/main/java/Entity.java")
    File file1 = file("../flavor1/main/java/Entity.java")
    File file2 = file("../flavor2/main/java/Entity.java")

    doLast {
        println "greendaoAfter"
        println "greendaoAfter ${flavor}"
        if (flavor == "flavor1") {
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file0)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file2)
        } else if (flavor == "flavor2") {
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file0)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file1)
        } else {
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file1)
            processer.processEntityAnnotation(true, file2)

        }


    }
}
```

register tasks:

```
tasks.configureEach { task ->
    if (task.name == "greendaoPrepare") {
        task.dependsOn('greendaoBefore')
    }
    if (task.name == "greendaoAfter") {
        task.dependsOn('greendao')
    }
    //If you haven't use kotlin, you can replace with annotationProcessor task name
    if (task.name.startsWith("kapt")) {
        task.dependsOn('greendaoAfter')
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of solution comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244940/20329042