# How to add if condition in build.gradle?

Tags: android, build.gradle

how can I apply plugin based on condition as bellow :

````
if(BuildConfig.Flavor=="example") 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'```
````

Comment: You can't do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31379795/7746134